# How to handle Login Successful in json?

Tags: java, android, json

I am trying to implement login and signup form in Android with the help of JSON using post method. When i signup and enter the details it successfully register and data has been shown in my local host sever and when i login its enter wrong username and password its show incorrect details in toast and enter right details shows login success in toast, but i want when i enter right details its goes to another activity. and enter wrong details shows only toast. Here is the code :-

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    public static HashMap<Sound, MediaPlayer> SOUND_MAP=
            new HashMap<Sound, MediaPlayer>();
    public static int userScore= 0, computerScore=0,
            buddyBoxId = 1, computerBoxId = 1;
    public static Context CTX;
    Button play;
    private static final String TAG = "LoginActivity";
    String URL = "http://10.0.2.2/test_android/index.php";
    JSONParser jsonParser=new JSONParser();
    ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    TextView register_caption;
    AdView adView = null;
    private AdView mAdView;
    EditText username, password;
    Button btnSignIn, btnRegister;
    ImageView fb;
    int i=0;
    private AdRequest adRequest;
    InterstitialAd mInterstitialAd;

    static MediaPlayer media;
    static Handler mediaHandler;
    public static int stat=0, totTurn = 0, maxEnd = 100;
    public static SharedPreferences configs;
    public static SharedPreferences.Editor configuration;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);
        password = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.passwordd);
        btnSignIn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.play);
        register_caption = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.register_caption);
        fb = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnfb);
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        progressDialog.setCancelable(false);



        btnSignIn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                         @Override
                                         public void onClick(View view) {
                                             AttemptLogin attemptLogin = new AttemptLogin();
                                             attemptLogin.execute(username.getText().toString(), password.getText().toString(), "");
                                         }
                                     });

        register_caption.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent in = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Registration.class);
                startActivity(in);


            }
        });

        CTX = getApplicationContext();
        configs = CTX. getSharedPreferences("snake_n_ladder", 0);
        configuration = configs.edit();
        loadConfig();
        loadMedia();
    }
    private class AttemptLogin extends AsyncTask<String, String, JSONObject> {

        @Override

        protected void onPreExecute() {

            super.onPreExecute();

        }

        @Override

        protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... args) {


            String email = args[2];
            String password = args[1];
            String name = args[0];

            ArrayList<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", name));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));
            if (email.length() > 0)
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", email));

            JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(URL, "POST", params);


            return json;

        }

        protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject result) {

            // dismiss the dialog once product deleted
            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),result,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            try {
                if (result != null) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), result.getString("message"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Unable to retrieve any data from server", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();

            }


        }

    }
```

JsonParser.java

```
public class JSONParser {


    static InputStream is = null;
    static JSONObject jObj = null;
    static JSONArray jArr = null;
    static String json = "";
    static String error = "";

    // constructor
    public JSONParser() {

    }

    // function get json from url
    // by making HTTP POST or GET mehtod
    public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method,
                                      ArrayList<NameValuePair> params) {

        // Making HTTP request
        try {

            // check for request method
            if(method.equals("POST")){
                // request method is POST
                // defaultHttpClient
                HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));
                try {
                    Log.e("API123", " " +convertStreamToString(httpPost.getEntity().getContent()));
                    Log.e("API123",httpPost.getURI().toString());
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                Log.e("API123",""+httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
                error= String.valueOf(httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();

            }else if(method.equals("GET")){
                // request method is GET
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
                url += "?" + paramString;
                HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();
            }

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            json = sb.toString();
            Log.d("API123",json);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        // try parse the string to a JSON object
        try {
            jObj = new JSONObject(json);
            jObj.put("error_code",error);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }

        // return JSON String
        return jObj;

    }

    private String convertStreamToString(InputStream is) throws Exception {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line);
        }
        is.close();
        return sb.toString();
    }

}
```

Comment: Time to get updated use [RetroFit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/) or some other networking library.

Comment: is it possible to do from this code? @ADM

Comment: Follow the link i have attached and you are good to go . its quite easy to implement. all documented .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject result) {

 try {
if (result != null) 
{
        if(result.getString("message").equals("Successfully logged in"))
        {
           Intent intent = new Intent(ThisActivity.this,NewActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }
        else
        {
        Toast.makeText(this,"Invalid credentials",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } 
} 
else 
{
   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Unable to retrieve any data from 
server", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
 } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: getting error in else part?

Comment: Please show me the error.

Comment: i got the error 'else' without 'if'

Comment: Please check now.

Comment: i put right password still its show invalid credentials

Comment: OK than what message you are sending when the credentials are right ? the same message you have to replace with "Login_successful"

Comment: In wrong and right both cases its work only invalid credential

Comment: When credentials is right i send login successfully and go to next activity and if its wrong than its so invalid username and password but in your given code both are working in invalid credential

Comment: I need to check that what message you are sending when the login is successful and when login is unsuccessful?

Comment: It’s 0 and 1 format

Comment: when incorrect details we put its shows the msg {"success":0,"message":"Incorrect details"} and when correcr details we put its shows {"success":1,"message":"Successfully logged in"}

Comment: I have updated the code as per your requirements, please check now.

Comment: Toast.makeText(this,"Invalid credentials",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); in this line i can use MainActivity. this right?

Comment: Thank you so much!!

Comment: No need to use 'MainActivity.this' just 'this' is fine.If you liked the answer please upvote it.

Comment: Welcome and keep sharing.